# Sync call in c#

Tags: c#, synchronous

I have Following API Call in c# and I want to make it Synchronous and it should wait till it comes backs from other modules where delete logic is performed.

Comment: I don't see any async code?  What am I missing please?

Comment: Why do you exactly want to make it sync? It's weird but review your return, since it's `async void` and it might be `async Task` and of course call your `CallExternalServiceAsync()` as `await CallExternalServiceAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

I belive the following code is your problem: CallExternalServiceAsync(..)

It should return a task, which you can await if you declare your function async. Otherwise, if you are just interested in waiting, you may call CallExternalServiceAsync(...).Wait(), assuming that it returns a Task.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on comments, you might return a `Task` instead a `void` and perform the call of the `CallExternalServiceAsync` method with the await, assuming it's awaitable.

```
public async Task CallDeleteOrderApi()
{
    var responseMsg = await CallExternalServiceAsync(_apiPath, _validatePath, requestHeader);
}
```

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await) which explains how and why using `async Task`.

Basically, just specify `async void` return on method declaration when it's on an Event (for example `frm_Load` on WinForms). On custom methods, always declare it as `async Task` if you would just return a `void` (which is actually returning a `Task`) and `async Task<int>` if you, for example, want to return an `int`.

Comment: Public HttpResponseMessage CallExternalServiceAsync(string apiUrl, string apiPath, FormUrlEncodedContent postContent)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl) };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Post implementation
            var response = client.PostAsync(apiPath, postContent).Result;
            return HttpResponseMessage;
        }

Comment: I have above  code for  CallExternalServiceAsync on on postasync it still dosent wait

Comment: @VitthalMokhare the problem is that you have to wait in your CallExternalServiceAsync clas for the result.